# how to use session in loopback using middlewre

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I m new to loopback and don't know how to do following things in loopback

1. I want to set  access token and other value  in a session using middleware  for that I found this thing in server folder of loopback

   ```
   "session": {},
   ```

   in middleware.json but don't know how to use this because there is not much documentation
2. I want to condition in session middleware like if I has session value then continue else  throw to login page

note i already install this  npm install express-session

Answer (score 2):

Could you be a little more specific about what you want? but I'll explain a little bit about how authentification sessions are handled, there are two native ways you treat it all; The first one would be using a more `raw reading` pulling for modeling of your api and the second would be to use the `JWT` in aligned with `accessToken` and `Passport.JS`.

There are two examples available today with [Loopback 3.x](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/)

- [loopback-example-user-management](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-user-management)
- [loopback-example-passport](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-passport)

Basically using the `raw reading` with `app.post('/login', function(req, res)` then if your client is successfully authenticated you generate a cookie using your client's accessToken, example `res.cookie('access_token', token.id, { signed: true , maxAge: 300000 }); res.set('X-Access-Token', token.id);` and finally if you want you can transport the generated token to your pages:

```
res.render('home', {
  email: req.body.email,
  accessToken: token.id
});
```

Now with Passport.JS a middleware is used to secure all your connection and authentication:

```
app.middleware('session:before', cookieParser(app.get('cookieSecret')));
app.middleware('session', session({
  secret: 'Seal Playing Saxophone',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
}));
passportConfigurator.init();
```

One of the authenticated page rendering pillar is `var ensureLoggedIn = require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn;` you can use this `ensureLoggedIn('/login')` to free up your routes:

```
app.get('/auth/account', ensureLoggedIn('/login'), function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('pages/loginProfiles', {
    user: req.user,
    url: req.url,
  });
});
```

Now if you just want to skip this all and already have your environment set up and just want to create a `route` to get the `accessToken` of the logged in client use the template below;

```
  app.get('/session-details', function (req, res) {
    var AccessToken = app.models.AccessToken;
    AccessToken.findForRequest(req, {}, function (aux, accesstoken) {
      // console.log(aux, accesstoken);
      if (accesstoken == undefined) {
        res.status(401);
        res.send({
          'Error': 'Unauthorized',
          'Message': 'You need to be authenticated to access this endpoint'
        });
      } else {
        var UserModel = app.models.user;
        UserModel.findById(accesstoken.userId, function (err, user) {
          // show current user logged in your console
          console.log(user);
          // setup http response
          res.status(200);
          // if you want to check the json in real time in the browser
          res.json(user);
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

I hope I have illuminated your ideas :] I am here to answer your questions.

Comment: thanks for your awesome explanation i want   before user login user select region like state name and when he select state according to that database connection established (note connection detail i m getting from master database) i.e on app start my app connect to master after that according to user selected state connection established these thing i want to handle through middleware

Comment: @rockysingh why not try to create specific login paths for the regions you want? at the time of the login request, it collect the desired region entered by the client, then uses it in the scope of the route address doing this you can render multiple pages using various parameters if you want I can make a practical example of this from the checkbox on the front end to the final rendering of the home page of each region for example

Comment: can you look into this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57271853/store-session-in-operation-hook-loopback